# interpretation of moderation in meta analysis

Tags: r, interaction, meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

I'm conducting a meta-analysis using package metafor in r and I want to test the possible moderation effect of 3 variables.

Of the 3 variables, only one gives me a significant effect on the 'Moderators effects', so I suppose I can say that only this variable has an effect. However, regarding the level of this moderator, no one is significative, and some of them have a CI that contains 0.

How can I interpret these results? The variable is a moderator but no level of the variable is statistically significant.

Comment: Taken as a whole the moderator has an effect but none of the categories is statistically significantly different from your reference category.

Comment: @mdewey THANKS for your reply!

Comment: You also might want to read this: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:diff_omnibus_vs_indiviual_tests